# Aggregate multiple log tables into one table; Outer Join?

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I have multiple tables in SQL Server 2008. They are various logging tables. Each table will have a `PersonID_FK` and a `Create` timestamp

I need to aggregate all of these tables for a particular `PersonID` key, such that I grab all record from any off the log tables where that person_ID key exists, and then sort all of the resulting rows by the `create timestamp`. I'm using LINQ to entities, and Entity Framework, but creating a view in the db seems like the best approach

See my SQL code below.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    dbo.person 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.log_items ON dbo.person.Id = dbo.log_items.personID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.Interactions ON dbo.person.Id = dbo.Interactions.personID
WHERE     
    (dbo.person.Id = 'a733ecf6-f414-4bcd-8b07-d6e12d313b95')
```

My resulting data from this query is only returning 2 rows, when I should have somewhere around 8 result rows.

Comment: Seems like a `UNION ALL` would be better than LEFT OUTER JOIN for what you're describing.

Comment: Start simple.  How many rows do you get back if you just query the person table with the same constraint on person.id?

Comment: As you want details of only specific person.Id then why are using LEFT JOIN, I think this query should work INNER JOIN too.

Comment: Originally I was working with a UNION ALL, but the different tables have different schema sets, where the only common column is PersonID FK, and a Create_Timestamp. SQL throws an error saying it must have an equal number of expressions in target list. If I just query person table, it returns 1 row.

Comment: When they all have different schema why are you trying to JOIN which are making no sense. Correct me if I am missing something. If log_items and Interactions have nothing to do with each other then create a proc and return both the resultsets from there

Comment: And how many rows for that ID do you have in each of the other two tables?

Comment: Can you include the table schemas? If you only need the PersonID and a date from each of the tables, you should still be able to use `Union All`